# Why is the bitset function not returning correct decimal value for binary strings like 1110 or 1011?

Tags: c++, string, binary, bitset

Here is my code that takes a 4 character string of 1's and 0's and converts to decimal using `bitset` function. It is returning correct values for all combinations except those involving 11's and 10's like `{1110,1010,1011,1111}`. For these numbers its returning the result ignoring MSB. That is for `1010` its giving 2 as the answer.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ul unsigned long

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int bin1=0,bin2=0,choice=0;
    ul x1=0,x2=0;
    //string binary;
    cin>>bin1;
    x1=bitset<4>(bin1).to_ulong();
    cin>>bin2;  
    x2=bitset<4>(bin2).to_ulong();
    cout<<x1<<" "<<x2<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

EDIT here is the snapshot of my results

[image]

Another snapshot of same program reading another set of input but this time it gives correct output. Btw the `1101` and `1001` are the inputs and the next two limes are the output

[image]

Comment: What did you enter? What did you get out? What did you expect to get out instead? Why?

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) And don't create type-aliases of standard types.

Comment: Basic debugging technique: check how simplification affects the problem. Does the same behavior occur with hardcoded inputs like `auto ten = "1010"` ? This excludes `std::cin` from the consideration and makes your question self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) overload of the bitset's constructor.

```
template<class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc>

explicit bitset( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& str,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type n =
                     std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::npos,
                 CharT zero = CharT('0'),
                 CharT one = CharT('1'));
```

From your use case looks like changing the type of `bin1` and `bin2` to `std::string` may just work.

Answer (score 6):

```
cout << bitset<4>(1010).to_ulong() << endl;
```

Prints 2.

---

```
cout << bitset<4>(0b1010).to_ulong() << endl;
```

Prints 10. (Note: [binary literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) were introduced in C++14)

---

From the [cppreference documentation of `std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset):

> `bitset( unsigned long val );`
>
> Constructs a bitset, initializing the first (rightmost, least significant) M bit positions to the corresponding bit values of val, where M is the smaller of the number of bits in an unsigned long long and the number of bits N in the bitset being constructed. [...]

`1010`'s bit representation is not `0b1010`, it's `0b1111110010` - which is too large for the bitset. That's why you're seeing unexpected results.

Comment: Not at all weird - it's doing exactly what the quoted text says, using the last four bits of the value it was given.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: `s/weird/unexpected/`

Answer (score 2):

When you input e.g. `1010` then that is the *decimal value* `1010`, which in binary is `1111110010`.

This is the value you initialize the bitset with. Since the bitset only contains four bits, the four lowest bits, which are `0010`, will be used.

Simple solution is to read the input as *strings*.

Comment: Thanks. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Bitset changes it's input into a binary represenation, so 0's and 1's
binary represenation of:

1010 -> 1111110010

1100 -> 10001001100

You're taking only 4 bits out of 32 (int usually has 4 bytes, 4*8 = 32 bits), so

1010 -> 0010 -> decimal 2

1100 -> 1100 -> decimal 12

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect but the code expresses itself clear enough. I extracted only the minimum required for the discussion:

```
int bin1=0;
cin>>bin1;
```

`bin1` is `int`. You read an `int` from `cin` and that `int` is `1010`. Which is **one thousand and ten**. No bits involved here.

In binary, `1010` (one thousand and ten) looks like this: `00000011 11110010`

```
x1=bitset<4>(bin1).to_ulong();
```

When the `bitset<4>` is constructed using the value of `bin1` only the `4` rightmost (least-significant) bits of `bin1` are used. These bits are `0010` and they represent the number `2`. The value of `x1` is `2`.

In a similar way, the value of `bin2` read from `cin` is `1110` (**one thousand, one hundred and ten**), its binary representation is `00000100 01010110`, its rightmost `4` bits are `0110` and they are the binary representation of the integer `6`.

The code does what it's supposed to do; your expectations are incorrect.

Read about [`bitset::bitset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset). It contains examples that should help you understand the difference.